# Initializing an array in declaration inside the function and using this outside

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I’d like to easily initialize an array inside the function:

```cpp
    int arr[]{1, 2, 3};
```

It simplifies calculating the size of the array:

```cpp
    int n  = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
```

However, I need this array to be preserved and be accessible outside the function.

How to do this?

For the start, I have this:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int n{0};
    int* g_arr{nullptr};

    void f()
    {
        int arr[]{1, 2, 3};

        n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
        g_arr = arr; // you can't use g_arr value outside this function, since arr will be freed.
    }

    void b()
    {
        cout << n;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cout << g_arr[i] << endl; // this is still wrong
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        f();
        b();
    }
```

Comment: You could have `int g_arr[3];` at file scope and assign the values in `f`

Comment: @M.M Not in my case. I need it inside the function.

Comment: In the code you have posted there is no need for `arr` inside the function. In fact it ceases to exist when `f` returns. If you have other requirements then you will need to detail them

Comment: @M.M Well, I need what I need. It would be very verbose to explain why. It leads to embeded programming and sparing the SRAM using PROGMEM.

Comment: Well you will need to try. The local array in the question stops existing when the function returns. If you're trying to say you create the array by some other means then obviously that is relevant to the question. Otherwise we just end up with an endless sequence of people suggesting answers and you saying "Oh that won't work for me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make arr[] static:

```cpp
 void f()
 {
    static int arr[]{1, 2, 3};

    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    g_arr = arr;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to copy the stack allocated array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int* g_arr = nullptr;
std::size_t n = 0;

void f() {
  int arr[]{1, 2, 3};

  n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

  delete[] g_arr;
  g_arr = new int[n];
  std::memcpy(g_arr, arr, sizeof(arr));
}

void b() {
  std::cout << n << '\n';

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    std::cout << g_arr[i] << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  f();
  b();
}
```

---

If you can, use a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> g_arr{};

void f() {
  g_arr = {1, 2, 3};  
}

void b() {
  std::cout << g_arr.size() << '\n';

  for (int const i : g_arr) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  f();
  b();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use vector. Templates library is not available in my environment and it wastes lots of SRAM.

Comment: Can you dynamically allocate `arr`?

Comment: I can. However I'll lose the conveniences of using `[]{…}`.

Comment: @zhekaus considering `[]{...}` is very important for you, I updated the answer

Comment: In the first case you can use `unique_ptr<int[]>` rather than a raw owning pointer

Comment: @M.M OP said they don't have the template library.